# Sas STP Putting javascript, Problems with jquery interpretation

Tags: jquery, sas

I have some stored processes in which put out some html and javascript, when i call them in browser (stored process web portal, Sas 9.3) they work:

Working example:

```
put '<script type="text/javascript">';
if _n_ = 1  then do;
put 'function spSDesc(index){';
put 'document.getElementById("descText").value=spDescs[index];';
/*or put "document.getElementById(%str(%"descText%")).value=spDescs[index];";*/
put '};';
put '</script>';
```

this works fine.

But now i want to do some jquery code, but it does not work that way:

```
put  " <script src=%STR(%"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js%")></script>";
put "  <script src=%STR(%"https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js%")></script>";
put "<script>";
put " $( function() {";
put " $(%str(%"#datepicker%")).datepicker();";
/* or put ' $("#datepicker").datepicker();';*/
put "  } );";
put "</script>";
```

gives me an error in browser:

mozilla firefox:

> 15:19:47.465 SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'1 do:1400:3

IE

> SCRIPT1002: Syntaxfehler Datei: do, Zeile: 1400, Spalte: 5

Code in browser:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>                                                                                                                                  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>                                                                                                                          
<script>                                                                                                                                                                                          
 $( function() {                                                                                                                                                                                  
 $(&quot;#datepicker&quot;).datepicker();                                                                                                                                                                    
  } );                                                                                                                                                                                            
</script>
```

So the `"` is not handled correct, if i use it in some jquery depended code (see that it worked correct for the script src= part).

Can somebody help me handle this problem? Do i need to escape the `"` in another way, or use other jquery code? Or does it not work with jquery at all?

EDIT:
As far as i understand the problem is:
The `&quot;` is not interpreted as `"`, so i get an syntaxerror
So i need the stp to write a `"`´ instead of `&quot;` or get jquery/javascript/browser to interpret `&quot;` as `"` inside the function.

**EDIT2 + Solution:**
On my working environment i only work with file _webout (and my workingexample is from there), i thought in my testenvironment i could use file print as equivalent, but i was wrong. I had not included my complete output  code in my example, so this was not solveable, i am sorry for that.

```
data _null_;

*file print; /*does not work correct with "*/

file _webout;/*does work correct with "*/

put ...... /*example code comes here*/


run;
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
data _null_;
put  ' <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>';
put  ' <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
put '<script>';
put ' $( function() {';
put ' $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();';
put '  } );';
put '</script>';
run;
```

**Option 2:**

Try this:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(
     $( function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     } );
    );
  </script>
```

Comment: That is the solution in the commented line of my post (the or part), did try that already, same effect. ' "text" ' and "%str(%"text%")" is equivalent

Comment: I have used jquery a lot with STP but  I normally download jquery to a local folder. Can you add the full error? or  is that all?

Comment: that is all firebug shows me. And of course, the date picker doees not work... I will work with jquery on own server later, this was just for testing, but the src part works , it is only the part in the function which does not work.

Comment: by the way does the css `id=datepicker` exists in your html?

Comment: yes, i only pasted the relevant part, because the full stp has many line of code and they are not relevant to this error. <input name="dttest" id="datepicker" type="text">

Comment: I would have suggested the same answer, I don't see how this is not working.

Comment: without seeing the html (at least the relevant bits) is difficult to replicate the error - can you wrap your function within a `$( document ).ready()` it may be the jquery fire off your function before the id exists....

Comment: @altons: can you explain this a bit more detailed how i should wrap the funtion? I am not used to work with jquery, only worked with native javascript before, just copied the datepicker part from a tutorial side... The storedprocess web server runs the stp in a frame, if this is also relevant...

Comment: other option is to put this code after `</html>` tag thus ensuring the html is created before jquery is added. So I suggest you have a data _null_ for your header, data _null_ for your htm body and a last _null_ for a footer in this case you would add the jquery to the footer.

Comment: see option2 in my answer - pls try to add a reproducible example of the error (remove confidential stuff) - gotta catch a train will check back when I get home

Comment: Hi, have to go now, but it seems that the problem depends on how i use the file option, if i do file print;  i get the error, if i use file _webout; i get no javascripterror but he can not load the external jquerycode. I have to test this later this week. I removed everything from my code, now i have just one datastep which only puts the input and the script code

Comment: Ok, i got it working. The problem was really about the file option. Using file print; does work in most cases had, but not in this specific one, file _webout; did work correct. So the problem was not in the code i posted (my bad), but the way i used the file option. But ty for your support.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid quoting issues with your javascript code, as well as to improve general readability, it's preferable to serve web files directly from the web server itself (eg ROOT.war if jboss).  You will get faster response times (can serve html before even connecting to SAS session), and a cleaner interface (serving data instead of modified markup).

Your approach of using `file print;` may have worked locally by sending html to the ODS destination, but `file _webout;` is always required for serving via the Stored Process Web Application broker.  You can still work on your web files locally this way by using the `--disable-web-security` command line flag (described [here](https://github.com/boemska/h54s#html5-data-adapter-for-sas-h54s)), but your SAS code needs to be running on an STP server. A guide for building STP web apps this way is available [here](http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/building-web-apps-with-sas.html) (full disclosure - I wrote it).